# PostGIS and R - Get data faster and in smaller size

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, leaflet, postgis

I have downloaded the Corine 2012 data about land coverage (available [here](http://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc-2012)), in order to use it for creating online a map via Shiny and Leaflet. I have uploaded the data in my PostgreSQL database and wish to use queries of data parts for my Shiny application. I began trying getting the data but it is quite slow and my main query leads to a 80 MB dataframe. How can I approach this differently in order to speed up getting the data and reduce its size? My code snippet (getting data for areas with coniferous plants) is:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(postGIStools)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL") # loads the PostgreSQL driver
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = mydbname, host = myhost, port = myport, 
             user = myuser, password = mypassword)
# Getting data
coniferous <- get_postgis_query(con, "SELECT id, geom from mycorine WHERE code='312'",geom_name = "geom")
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've had quite a lot of joy using `rpostgis` and `sf` when extracting large amounts of vector data from postgis into R. Also incorporate [ST_Simplify](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Simplify.html) to speed up geometry displays in Leaflet:

```
# set up connection
conn <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL",user="user",password="mypass",port=5432,dbname="postgis_name")

# dummy query (obviously), including a spatial subset and ST_Simplify to simplify geometry
qry <- "SELECT ST_Simplify(geom,60) AS geom FROM mytable WHERE geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, EPSG)"

the.data = st_read_db(conn, query=qry, geom="geom")
```

this will return simplified sf objects, which are read in as a data frame and are very quick to read into R.

The above query was against 600,000 polygons and subset by a bounding box that read in about 8,000 of them. It took 0.4 seconds. Obviously this could be done by attribute instead of spatial bounding box (query times may differ though).

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf

You should always take into account how much data is reasonable to display and what level of geometrical detail is acceptable at your zoom level etc.

Comment: A great answer that works! However, I need a more efficient solution since this solution decreases indeed my query size by 43% but the time getting this data amounts about to 10 sec. Is there another way or is my server too slow?

Comment: I have a query of 80 MB and I wouldl ike to reduce it for example to 10 MB. I used ST_Simplify but it mostly produced null polygons, so I tried ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology with 43% reduction.

Comment: your best bet is GeoJSON, but i'm still working on that. I believe sf objects would be quicker than a SPDF

Comment: I see.. OK then, I will wait until Friday for any other views or opinions, and if none appear, I will accept your answer which is of course correct and functional.

Comment: postGIStools::get_postgis_query does not work for me, no matter what i try. Have you considered reading polygons as simple features from PostGIS?   st_read_db(conn, query=qry, geom="geom"). It really is quite a bit quicker.